# Subsequent Windows 10 install, what to consider?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, windows-10

I have a dual boot Ubuntu on my Lenovo X230. Linux One is unencrypted on `sda2` (family, guests, tinkering), Linux Two (work) is encrypted within `sda5`:

```
NAME                    TYPE  FSTYPE      MOUNTPOINT
sda                     disk
├─sda1                  part  ext2        /boot
├─sda2                  part  ==> my Linux One (Elementary OS)
└─sda5                  part  crypto_LUKS ==> my Linux Two (Ubuntu-Mate)
    └─sda5_crypt          crypt LVM2_member
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   lvm   ext4        /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 lvm   swap        [SWAP]
```

**Question: If I boot from my Windows 10 boot media, install Windows to sda2 (overwriting my Linux One), what bad things will happen, that I need to look into before/after windows 10 install?**

- What about the boot partion?
- What about restoring the bootsector afterwards? (I believe, I am on UEFI, on this 4-year-old machine…)
- Can the Win10 install harm the other partitions? (within the W10 setup, of course I will go for „expert mode“ and picking the partition to install to...)
- I'd assume, I better boot with a linux stick before and backup `/boot/grub` before?

**What will I have to do after windows install?**

Comment: Ubuntu itself [provides some infos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) – I am still a bit scared...

Comment: [image the drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) and you won't have to be scared.

Comment: `This question was marked as an exact duplicate`.
– It clearly is not: The partitioning situation is entirely different, bootloader already exists. No repartitioning. Ubuntu is already in a to-be-preserved placed. Including encryption. … :-/